# Best way to store table data without the use of a database?

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I need to store data from parsed `XML`, I have no problem with the parsing, that I can handle. The problem is that I receive a table data basically where each time the column names, columns number and the data it self are different. Now I don't want to use `SQLite` Database as I have a small number of entries and I don't see it feet for this situation. I even think I can't use it as I will have to create a new table for each data set I will receive. Now to be more clear here is some examples:

```
 <Details1_Collection>
    <Details1 ProductName="Bicycle" Units="2341" DefectedUnits="125" />
    <Details1 ProductName="Television" Units="3154" DefectedUnits="75" />
    <Details1 ProductName="Keyboard" Units="2413" DefectedUnits="12" />
    ...
  </Details1_Collection>
```

or another `XML`:

```
 <Details_Collection>
    <Details HireDate="2003-02-15T00:00:00" JobTitle="Chief Executive Officer"  BirthDate="1963-03-02T00:00:00" />
    <Details HireDate="2002-03-03T00:00:00" JobTitle="Vice President of Engineering" BirthDate="1965-09-01T00:00:00" />
    <Details HireDate="2001-12-12T00:00:00" JobTitle="Engineering Manager" BirthDate="1968-12- 13T00:00:00" />
    ...
 <Details_Collection>
```

Now you can notice that the XML tags are different: `Details1_Collection` and `Details_Collection`
, `Details1` and `Details` and I will receive a new tag set almost each time. But that is not a problem for me, because I receive them in a sooner call to the server so I know what tags I should parse. I don't need to store the Attributes as well names as I already have those too. I need to store only the values.

**The Question:**

How should I store the Attributes data which basically is a table data but It's a different table with different column names and number each time? I would prefer to not store this data as is as a `String/Dom` element inside of it's parent object but ratter to parse it into some java
data structure that can be accessed easily on the UI thread.

**In Short:**

This data is a part of a bigger object and my goal is to parse it into some kind of data structure and attach it as part of the parent class.

Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: You could store the attributes using an XML format, since you already have an XML parser in your application.

Comment: I could do that, but eventually I would have to parse this data to a some kind of a java object so I could access it on the UI thread. because the parsing is performed using an AsyncTask in the background.

Comment: Why not make a parsing methods an interface and implement the interface two way, parse on UI and parse off UI

Comment: Are there really any data structure in java language that could store this type of data? I don't need to store the Attributes names as I already have those. I need to store only the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stumbled on the following forum post:

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/696-multi-dimension-arraylist-example.html

There is an implementation of ArrayList of ArrayLists, this is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList2d<Type>
{
ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>  array;

public ArrayList2d()
{
    array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>();
}

/**
 * ensures a minimum capacity of num rows. Note that this does not guarantee
 * that there are that many rows.
 * 
 * @param num
 */
public void ensureCapacity(int num)
{
    array.ensureCapacity(num);
}

/**
 * Ensures that the given row has at least the given capacity. Note that
 * this method will also ensure that getNumRows() >= row
 * 
 * @param row
 * @param num
 */
public void ensureCapacity(int row, int num)
{
    ensureCapacity(row);
    while (row < getNumRows())
    {
        array.add(new ArrayList<Type>());
    }
    array.get(row).ensureCapacity(num);
}

/**
 * Adds an item at the end of the specified row. This will guarantee that at least row rows exist.
 */
public void Add(Type data, int row)
{
    ensureCapacity(row);
    while(row >= getNumRows())
    {
        array.add(new ArrayList<Type>());
    }
    array.get(row).add(data);
}

public Type get(int row, int col)
{
    return array.get(row).get(col);
}

public void set(int row, int col, Type data)
{
    array.get(row).set(col,data);
}

public void remove(int row, int col)
{
    array.get(row).remove(col);
}

public boolean contains(Type data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (array.get(i).contains(data))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int getNumRows()
{
    return array.size();
}

public int getNumCols(int row)
{
    return array.get(row).size();
}
}
```

This is the best way I found by this moment to store the data I want to store.
What do you think, Java experts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot perform the typical Java Serialization? As in, create classes that represent your data, let them implement `Serializable`, and just read and write the whole object graph to a file using `Object(Input|Output)Stream`s?

Keep in mind this only works if your whole object graph will fit into memory.

Comment: do you have maybe a code example on how it's done? I have never performed a typical Java Serialization. this means that the class that represent my data should be created at run time. and I have no idea how it's done.

Comment: Dude, googling for `java serialization tutorial` gives http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm as the second hit.

Comment: sorry, I just didn't know what to look for. I will look into that. Thanks you for your help.